# when the pdf orientation is landscape the pdf width is not occupied fully even though width is 100%

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

When my `pdf report` is having `landscape` orientation.The Header table is not taking full width even though width for Header table is given 100%, and margin-right for pdf report is 1cm applied but still full width is not occupied for header

If my pdf report is having `portrait` orientation header width is fully occupied problem is with only When my pdf report is having `landscape` orientation, can anyone please help me.

my css for table is

```
table
{
width:100%
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it out locally, and you should be able to get there with this:

```
# controller
render pdf: 'foo',
       orientation: 'Landscape',
       margin: { top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }
```

Note the setting of margins on the PDF itself.

```
# stylesheet
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and the removal of padding and margin on the HTML body tag that wraps the table (whether you add one or not, webkit will).